# IOS Change Listing Style (Grid or List)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i have an UITableView that use, my CUITableViewCell. My UITableviews each row has been filled by specified cell identifier like :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat @"cell_row_%d",ProductId]//(ProductId is uniq value)
```

Everything is okey, thats work perfect but now i have to add a switch button that switch the tableviewcell style to box style like android gridview, ios collection view. For exp, if you click List style there is nothing need to be change, but if you click Box Style, the table must be change to box style. How can i do uniq identifier for UICollectionViewCells each row?

Comment: Why are you giving each cell its own reuse identifier?  This removes one of the performance advantages of UITableView, which is cell reuse.

Comment: Because each row has components like + and - button that set the value in cell, if the user click the button +  then scroll the tableview, my datas were lost, so that each row has their own id

Comment: That approach is incorrect - you should be storing that data outside of the cell, and then setting the data to the correct value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I know but, my cells were filled from NSMutableArray that came from the outside of the cell. But some values which were set by the user. So that how can i pass again the data to cell from to NSMutableArray. I used my CustomCell class.

Comment: I'm happy to help you with that, but it's off-topic for this question.  I suggest you post it as a separate question, with more details about your data and table view implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your time @AaronBrager, How can i contact with you about my issue detail?

Answer (score 0):

You've to create a UICollectionView with your UIcollectionViewCell and add it as a subview to your current view, hiding the current UITableView.

Comment: How may i can use the properties that was set in my CUITableViewCell, and how can i use my collectionviewcell like this uniq style : [NSString stringWithFormat @"cell_row_%d",ProductId]

Comment: Do you want to show a string in your collection view cell?

Comment: My CUITableviewCell have more than 6-7 properties. Like my custom UIButtons, UILabel, NSMutableArray.. etc So that my CUICollectionViewCell may have to  use NSMutableArray that defined in my CUITableViewCell

Comment: You can create your custom UIView and add it as a subview of your UICollectionViewCell in your - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: How do you populate your UITableViewCell? If you load an array of NSObject you can store your text in a property of your selected object (using the textFieldReturn method of the textfield used) and then you've already the needed data in the UICollectionView datasource.

Comment: i filled my tableView from NSMutableArray, this array has my models instance, this is ok. But there is user attraction in each row, when user change the value of row how can i pass this to my root array.

Answer (score 0):

To pass values from i.e. an UITextField inside your custom cell to your source model, you have to trigger its -(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender method in order to get the reference to the cell in this way:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender

  //Get the superview from this txtfield which will be our cell

  UITableViewCell *owningCell;

  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
  } else {
    owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
  }

  //From the cell get its index path.
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForCell:owningCell];
```

Comment: My cell is CUITableViewCell so that, there is no cell UI component in my viewcontroller. All of Cells UI components were defined in CUITableViewCell  class. So that when user click a button the method which  defined in the CUITableViewCell class were triggered by the user. There may be delegate to pass data, cell to viewcontroller but, i call the cell like [NSString stringWithFormat @"cell_row_%d",ProductId] specific identifier. CUICollectionView does not allow to use with unique identifier for each row.

Comment: At this time i just want to know, how i can use UICollectionViewCell identifier, like table cell identifier [NSString stringWithFormat @"cell_row_%d",ProductId]. Collection view does not allow this. This is my main issue

Comment: Why don't you use an incremental tag number in your components, so you can easily access to them by using the [sender tag] UIView property?

Comment: so that why the xcode UITableview use the identifier, they solve this issue with tag. But my problem is not solved with the tag :( i am still working about it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `UICollectionView` in both cases? When the list has to be changed to a grid, just change the size of each cell.

Comment: is it possible to change Grid square view to UITableviewCell view style? Just think about a second if its possible then how can i call the CollectionViewCell like this unique identifier: [NSString stringWithFormat @"cell_row_%d",ProductId] FOR EACH CELL.

Comment: You can create a UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout and change the itemSize property's width to full or half. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/itemSize